# Texture seen in viewport is paler compared to the original texture

Tags: texturing, uv, 3d-view

Issue:
[image]

My textures in the viewport look darkened or desaturated when compared to viewing it in the UV window.
Should I adjust the colors of the texture?  or is this a a Blender issue that can be solved with some settings? My goal is to make the viewport 100% reflect the colors of the textures.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

You are now in the viewport shading - material preview. So your color depends on the lighting you have chosen here. You can change your lighting by tapping on that shading button.[image]

Then choose another lighting you like by tapping on the sphere.

You can even import your own .hdr lighting by tapping on that gear icon.

Answer (score 0):

As Chris says, you are in *Material Preview*, you can tweak the options in the panel. I don't know if there's a setting that allow to see the materials without lights and shadows but for a given material you could temporarily plug the *Image Texture* directly into the *Output* node, it will act like an *Emission* shader:

[image]

Also, make sure that in the *Render panel > Color Management*, you are in Standard and not in *Filmic* mode, *Filmic* make colors look paler.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out. Thanks to everyone!

Additional inquiry: Am I going to encounter the same issue when I import my model to Unity or will it be fixed when I use my toon shader?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong Color Space.

Images viewed in the wrong Color space will always look wrong. The default color space on blender is "filmic", designed for work on cycles with a high dynamic range. Since you are not doing that, you need a different setting.

If your textures are all images on sRGB color space, then set the view transform to ***Standard*** in the Color Management Section of the output settings.